# g++ compiling for linux only cross-platform

Tags: c++, linux, g++, cross-platform

I'm interested in setting up a remote server to run some intensive computations.  For various reasons, I might want to run a different linux distro than that of my dev box.  Assuming the hardware is properly target, and I limit myself to ISO C libraries, can expect any problems running an executable on a linux distribution different from that which the code is g++-compiled?

In my specific case, my dev box is latest Ubuntu-based.  Is there any linux distro on which the Ubuntu-based g++-compiled code will get hung up?  When selecting the remote server distro, what should I look for that will ensure trouble free operation?

Comment: Will both boxes have the same CPU?

Comment: The server would most likely be a faster/RAM-ier version of dev box.  Or at least, dev box is a within-the-family or a previous gen CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I run a lot of computationally intense code that I've developed for my work on both my laptop and a desktop. Until I recently had to replace my laptop, it was a much slower machine with much less RAM than my desktop, so it was a similar situation to what you describe.

If your code is computationally intense, you're likely going to want it to be optimized for whatever machine it is running on, whether that be your dev box or the remote server. I think the easiest thing to do would be to setup a makefile for your code, so that you can copy the makefile and the source over to the remote server, then as long as both the dev box and server the same version of gcc and any other library dependencies your code needs, you should simply have to issue the make command to build the code on the remote server. If you need a quick tutorial on makefiles, [this](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/) one was helpful for me when I first started using them.

The benefit of doing things this way is that you can develop and test the code on one computer using a smaller data set, lower resolution grid, or whatever you need to do to reduce the computational intensity. Then once you know its working, transfer it over to a more powerful machine to actually run the more intense version. By calling the make command, g++ can then use flags like `-march=native` or `-mtune=native` to ensure the code is optimized for the CPU of the remote server, and since it was compiled on that machine, you shouldn't have to worry about whether the executable built on one computer can just run on another one.

Comment: Thanks for your time and attention.  I understand the exact logic and issues you cite in your recommendation, but that is exactly not the solution I'm looking for.  I just want to know what are the issues to look for when executing code on a different Linux platform than the dev box, given the hardware are mostly the same but for reasons unspecified, the Linux distro might have to be different.